# Custom Component shuffles listview

Tags: android, listview

I am making bar charts in custom list view. when I scroll list, components get shuffle. How can it be stopped.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.stats_row_layout, null);
        }

        Stat stat = objects.get(position);

        if (stat.isFlag()) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        }

        if (!stat.isExist()) {
            stat.setExist(true);

            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statGraphLayout);
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();

            if (stat.getmView() == null) {
                ImageView mView = new StatBarChartVie(context, stat.getStatValues());
                stat.setmView(mView);
            }

            LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 50);
            stat.getmView().setLayoutParams(params);

            linearLayout.addView(stat.getmView());

                            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the null check for convert view.

Comment: I tried it, but did not work. It just remove all components.

Comment: Are these items added dynamically..? How are you updating the list view  when new item is added..?

Comment: Yes, these items add dynamically, I add items in arraylist and call notifyDataSetChanged(). `statsList.clear(); statsList.addAll(db.getAllStats()); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: If you are dealing with database, I suggest CursorAdapter is best one. The Listview will be updated automatically when a column data is changed without shuffling. Otherwise you may need to create the adapter every time the item is added to avoid shuffling.

Comment: Items are added only once and then i give that list to listadapter. Item does not add after i give that statList to adater.

Comment: Usually this happens when re-creating the views when the user scrolls the list (Depends on your custom list view implementation). In getView() method re-creating the layout should work. To avoid all these refresh problems better to use CursorAdapter.

Comment: Views are creating only once.

Comment: Then check your custom ListView. Put some Logs in getView() and prints the values and check whether the values are retrieving properly and updated in layout while scrolling the ListView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16974/discussion-between-nuraiz-and-knvarma)

Answer (score 0):

Using the visible / gone flags doesn't seem right in a list view.

Because of how a list view recycles views, that is probably the problem. 
You may need to be a bit smarter about how you access the array.  And not include invisible items in the count.

Whenever you change the data ( possibly overriding notifyDataSetChanged() calling its super), you could create a new Index ArrayList with only the values which are visible.  So you no longer need to use the invisible settings.  This way you only loop through the array on data changes.